# Значение выражения с двумя тернарными операторами

Tags: javascript

```
i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max(0, len + i) : i : 0;
```

Я думаю, что это выражение эквивалентно

```
if (i == i) {
    if (i < 0) {
        i = Math.max(0, len + i);
    }
    else {
        i = i;
    }
}
else
    i = 0;
```

Верно ли я интерпретировала код?
Вопрос: чему равен `i` и чему равен `Math.max(0, len + i)`?
То есть, как я понимаю, `i` равен самому себе.

Comment: чтоб не гадать - надо скобки расставлять

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ,"используется для проверки корректности i", например?Просто не поняла."Math.max(0, len + i) в данный момент ничему не равно, ибо показано для примера", почему, или значение равно "NAN"? Просто , если запустить скрипт, то возникает ошибка в данном месте. Подскажите, плииз

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выражение `i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max(0, len + i) : i : 0;` эквивалентно следующему:

```
if ( i ) {
    if ( i < 0 ) {
        i = Math.max(0, len + i);
    } else {
        i = i;
    }
} else {
    i = 0;
}
```

P.S. если это взято из статьи "Как писать неподдерживаемый код", то это выражение там сугубо ради примера, который ярко указывает на то, что так кодить не стоит (ибо читаемость крайне затруднительна) и глубокого смысла не несёт.

Comment: похоже на часть полифила для slice

Comment: А какой может быть смысл у `i = i ?` и чем это отличается от просто `i ?`?

Comment: @andy.37, там не `(i=i)?...:...`,  там `i = (i? ... : ...)`

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, понял. В том числе и то, что так писать *нельзя никогда*

Comment: @andy.37, но если очень хочется, то можно :-D

Comment: @andy.37 в данном случае можно и написать, ибо если расставить скобки внутри - то сразу станет понятно что к чему относится..... а в целом, если конструкция будет сложнее и тем более еще с бОльшей вложенностью - то конечно не желательно писать так

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `if (i<0) { i = max(0, len + i); }` - разве не эквивалент?

Comment: @andy.37 эквивалент чего?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский исходного выражения. Ведь если i==0 -> i=0, i>0 -> i=i

Comment: @andy.37 я не понял, что вы мне хотите показать....я вам говорю, что `i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max(0, len + i) : i : 0;` вполне можно писать, если расставить скобки для читаемости? хотя бы так `i = i ? (i < 0 ? Math.max(0, len + i) : i) : 0;` ..... а если у вас конструкция `i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max(0, len + i) : i : i > 5 ? i++ : i<3 ? i*2: 0;` или еще какой-нибудь громоздкий и трудночитаемый бред - тогда не стоит громодить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я к тому, что `if (i<0) { i = Math.max(0, len + i); }` сделает ровно то же, что и `i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max(0, len + i) : i : 0;`, ровно на символ длиннее и в 100500 раз понятнее.

Comment: @andy.37 первое условие if (i) несёт глубокий смысл и опускать его нельзя. а с ним конструкция становится более громоздкой, чем с тернарным оператором

Comment: @andy.37 нет...не правда...во что выльется вся конструкция `i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max(0, len + i) : i : 0;` вам написали в ответе....потому что при разном изначальном значении `i` - разные результаты оператора будут..........как итог -.можете посчитать сколько там (в ответе) символов.

Comment: @lexxl, в Javascript пожалуй да, согласен. Почему-то считал это Java. Сорри за флуд.

Comment: @lexxl, Спасибо за ответ. Что означает выражение `if (i) ` и чему равно `Math.max(0, len + i)`. Ведь `len`, как я поняла , не определен.

Comment: @NNN `if (i)` проверяет, равно ли булево значение переменной `i` значению `true` - используется, скажем так,  для проверки корректности данных в переменной перед их использованием. `Math.max(0, len + i)` в данный момент ничему не равно, ибо показано для примера

Comment: @lexxl,"используется для проверки корректности i", например?Просто не поняла."Math.max(0, len + i) в данный момент ничему не равно, ибо показано для примера", почему, или значение равно "NAN"? Просто , если запустить скрипт, то возникает ошибка в данном месте. Подскажите, плииз.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if (i == i){
> ```

Неверно думаешь. Тут

```
if (i) {
```

Остальное вроде да.